# How to make (Copy to clipboard )with br break line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, clipboard

I am trying to copy text to clipboard immediately in a new line. Sure when I click the copy button then paste it in (post, website, blogger, forum,notepad and etc) it will be the same as you where to copy it.
more explain:

This is the text looks like before I copy it

```
Some commonly sold digital good include:
1- eBooks.
2- Audiobooks.
3- Pictures and Videos.
4- Digital Music.
5- Software programs.
```

However when I copy and paste it in notepad it will appear only in one line  like this

> Some commonly sold digital good include:1- eBooks.2- Audiobooks.3-
>   Pictures and Videos.4- Digital Music.5- Software programs.

Here the JS that I am talking about.

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}

 var addrsField = $('.input_copy .txt');
$('.input_copy .icon').click(function() {
        copyToClipboard('.input_copy .txt');
        addrsField.addClass('flashBG').delay('1000').queue(function(){
            addrsField.removeClass('flashBG').dequeue();
        });
    });
```

I would like, if possible, to have the text look like when we first copied it

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/null000/pen/wjqYVN

Comment: `input` element can't contain line breaks, its content is plain text. Use `textarea` instead of `input`.

Comment: Try making `$temp` a `<textarea>`, delimiting `element` by the periods, and adding a `\n` after each period

Comment: Just `temp` as textarea works fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvywRw

Comment: @ Teemu , yes yours works well , but how i can insert \r\n  for windows users and where can it be , can you please add them , or does not matter \r\n ?i really do not know ,

Comment: If the source contains new-lines, the clipboard makes the new-lines automatically, you don't have to worry about them, not even in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Just change:

```
var $temp = $("<input>");
```

To :

```
var $temp = $("<textarea>");
```